# Where is the hook to display the newly added item in woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created my own theme and made have been editing the Woocom created pages. On the product singles page when I click "add to cart" it generates that number of "x" added to cart. From there you can also see the "view cart option" How do I add this to another page? I can't find the hook for it. I think it also may be a javascript function on click.

[image]

Here is the code inside content-single-product.php

```
global $product;

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_product.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_all_notices - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    echo get_the_password_form(); // WPCS: XSS ok.
    return;
}
?>

//The view cart link is added before the div below
<div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?>>

    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_product_summary.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary">
```

Is there an easy way to call the after add to cart code to a certain place on the page. Ex. an if statement if they added to cart? Sorry, I feel this question is super simple, but I am finding learning woocommerce a little confusing. I feel I need to find this file  -  `woocommerce_output_all_notices`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get the notices that are created by adding items to cart, or if there's an error of some sort, you can invoke the function `wc_get_notices()` or `wc_print_notices()`.

`woocommerce_output_all_notices()` does the same thing as `wc_print_notices()` but adds an HTML wrapper around the content. You can view it's exact detail in the [reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.3692).

If you want to add a notice to appear, then you can use `wc_add_notice()` which should then print out when notices are printed out.

Comment: Yes, this resource is great! thanks. I will definitely use this reference often during my development now. I would like to give it a container and make it display a certain way now. I'll have to edit this hook specifically.